# Character encoding problems

Tags: vim, character-encoding

I attempted to convert a file I wrote in Vim to UTF-8.  Vim defaulted the encoding to `us-ascii`.  I ran this command: `recode UTF-8 [filename]`.  It reported no errors, but when I run: `file -i [filename]` it still stays encoding is ASCII.  Is this a known error or expected result? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Is there any non-ASCII characters in your file?  If not, the behavior you describing is expectable: UTF-8 is fully backward-compatible with ASCII, so any valid ASCII file is automatically a valid UTF-8 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say that if your file is just ascii character, there is no difference in the final file between the ascii encoding and utf8 encoding, cause for ascii character, the utf8 encoding is exactly the same as ascii encoding.

But if your file contains some non-ascii character, you will see the difference.

Your "fileencodings" setting for vim may use "ascii" before "utf8", that's the list that vim try to detect the file encodings. So if the file can be read as "ascii", the later utf8 will not be tried anymore, although utf8 is also correct.